# ADMA0002E: A validation error occurred in task Binding enterprise Bean to JNDI

Tags: web-services, websphere

While installing the current package, the following error messages are received:

1. *WASX7017E*: Exception received while running file `/opt/Install_SIPR/updateSiprEar.py`; exception information: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7108E: Invalid data specified for install task: "BindJndiForEJBNonMessageBinding."  Errors are: "
2. *ADMA0002E*: A validation error occurred in task Binding enterprise Bean to JNDI names. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified for enterprise bean DqEvalPersistService in module GfmEjb.
3. *ADMA0002E*: A validation error occurred in task Binding enterprise Bean to JNDI names. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified for enterprise bean JumService in module GfmEjb."

The messages are associated to the following statement:

```
AdminApp.update(appName, 'app', '[ -operation update -contents ' + earFileName + ' -nopreCompileJSPs -installed.ear.destination $(APP_INSTALL_ROOT)/' + cell + ' -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -deployejb -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -nodeployws -validateinstall warn -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -filepermission .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink -MapResRefToEJB [[ GfmEjb EventHandlerMDB GfmEjb.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml mail/DefaultMail javax.mail.Session mail/DefaultMail "" "" "" ][ GfmWebServices "" GfmWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml mail/DefaultMail javax.mail.Session mail/DefaultMail "" "" "" ][ GfmWebServices "" GfmWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml GfmOracle javax.sql.DataSource jdbc/GFMDS "" "" "" ][ GfmEjb EventHandlerMDB GfmEjb.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml GfmOracle javax.sql.DataSource jdbc/GFMDS "" "" "" ]] -MapModulesToServers [[ GfmEjb GfmEjb.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml ' + installString + ' ][ GfmWebServices GfmWeb.war,WEB-INF/web.xml ' + installString + ' ]]]' )
```

NOTE:  the installString contains cell, node, appServer, allwebservers, and allwebserverNodes information.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is simply saying that there is an EJB in the application that does not have a JNDI name specified for it. I think adding this:

> -BindJndiForEJBNonMessageBinding [[ "GfmEjb" JumService GfmEjb.jar,META-INF/ejb-jar.xml ejb/JumService ]]

to the command should fix this problem.